# executing the powershell commands using python

Tags: python-3.x, powershell

```
import os
os.system("powershell.exe [Get-ItemProperty 
  HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\*| Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize > D:\\application whitelisting\\InstalledProgramsPS.txt ]")
```

this is my code. I want to display the list of software installed in the system.

but i am getting error like 
Select-Object is not recognized as an external or internal command.
when i execute the same command using powershell, it is working fine.

can anyone please help?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that Powershell's command parameter is not properly constructed. `os.system()` call will star a CMD session, and `Select-Object is not recognized as an external or internal command` is an error message from CMD.

Let's see what CMD does. First it will run Powershell and pass some arguments. Note the triple backslash, which is an error by itself and needs to be fixed.

```
powershell.exe [Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\*
| Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate
```

Now, the first thing is that Powershell is invoked and (wrongly) paramerized Get-ItemProperty is passed. Because the pipe char `|` is used in CMD as well, it is interpreted as a command for CMD. Thus CMD tries to pipe the first command's output to `Select-Object`, but there isn't such a command in CMD. Thus the error.

To fix the issue, use `-command "<commands>"` to pass commands to Powershell. The double quotes `"` are used to create a single string that CMD passes to Powershell as an argument.

```
powershell.exe -command "Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\*| Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table -AutoSize > D:\\application whitelisting\\InstalledProgramsPS.txt"
```